# What is the difference between Sp(2)S^1 and Sp(2)?

Tags: lie-groups

I am reading B. Wilking's publication, which said that $Sp(2)S^1$ is the normalizer of $Sp(2)\subset SU(5)$. I consider that $Sp(2)$ can be embedded into $SU(5)$ by $A+jB\rightarrow$ 
$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
A & -\overline{B} & 0\\
B & \overline{A} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$. But I don't know what is $Sp(2)S^1$ stands for. Is it $Sp(2)\times S^1$? It's my pleasure if someone can help me.

Comment: $S^1$ can be described as the matrix $diag(τ,τ,τ,τ,1/τ)$ where $τ=e^{iθ}$, so $Sp(2)S^1$ stands for $Sp(2)×S^1$.

Comment: The only issue is that $(\tau, \tau, \tau, \tau, 1/\tau) \notin SU(5)$ in general. Maybe we can use $(\tau, \tau, \tau, \tau, \tau^{-4})$.

Comment: For two subgroups G and H of some ambient group, the notation GH presumably means all elements of the form gh when g in G and h in H. When G and H commute, this is a quotient of GxH.

Comment: The difference between $Sp(2)S^1$ and $Sp(2)\times S^1$ is that in the first case the two factors may have a nontrivial intersection. In your case it is $\langle{\rm diag}(-1,-1,-1,-1,1)\rangle$.